# Matlab dec2bin gives wrong values

Tags: matlab

I'm using Matlab's dec2bin to convert decimal number to binary string. However, I'm getting wrong results. For example:

```
>> dec2bin(13339262925365424727)

ans =

1011100100011110100101001111010011000111111100011011000000000000
```

I checked both in a C++ implementation and in wolfram alpha and the correct result is:

```
1011100100011110100101001111010011000111111100011011001001010111
```

Is there any problem with my usage of Matlab's desc2bin?

Thanks,

Gil.

Comment: [this question addresses the opposite direction, using bin2dec](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32334748/2732801)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
x=13339262925365424727;
dec2bin(x)
```

but if you check the value of x, you will notice that it outruns double precision. The number is simply to large to be stored in a 64bit double. The precision is 2^11, check `eps(x)`

To deal with large numbers, using `vpa` from the symbolic toolbox is a good option, is this available?

Here is a solution using vpa:

```
function l=ldec2bin(x)
if x>2^52
    head=floor(x/2^52);
    tail=x-head*2^52;
    l=[ldec2bin(head),dec2bin(double(tail),52)];
else
    l=dec2bin(double(x));
end
end
```

usage:

```
>> ldec2bin(vpa('13339262925365424727'))

ans =

1011100100011110100101001111010011000111111100011011001001010111
```

/Update:

I came across a much shorter implementation of `dec2bin` for symbolic variables:

```
>> sdec2bin=@(x)(feval(symengine,'int2text',x,2))

sdec2bin = 

    @(x)(feval(symengine,'int2text',x,2))

>> sdec2bin(sym('13339262925365424727'))

ans =

1011100100011110100101001111010011000111111100011011001001010111
```

Answer (score 2):

The integer seems to long, maybe you should try `de2bi` function;
http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/de2bi.html

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue. `fliplr(char(de2bi(13339262925365424727)+48))` is identical to `dec2bin(13339262925365424727)`. The documentation for `de2bi` doesn't mention it, it appears that it also is implemented using double precision and thus may return inaccurate output for values greater than `flintmax`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the input is less than `intmax('uint64')`, as in the example, here is a solution that doesn't require the Symbolic Math toolbox. This supports two input arguments, matching [`dec2bin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html), is vectorized, and should be much faster:

```
function s=int2bin(d,n)
%INT2BIN  Convert nonnegative integer to a binary string
if isempty(d)
    s = '';
    return;
end
d = d(:);
if ~isinteger(d) || any(d < 0)
    error('int2bin:InvalidIntegerInput',...
          'First input must be a nonnegative integer class array.');
end
if nargin < 2
    n = 1
else
    n = round(double(n));
end
m = double(nextpow2(max(d)));
s = [repmat('0',length(d),n-m) rem(bsxfun(@bitshift,d,1-m:0),2)+'0'];
```

If you don't mind a bit less performance and prefer a one-line anonymous function, try:

```
int2bin = @(d,n)char(rem(bsxfun(@bitshift,d(:),1-max(n,double(nextpow2(max(d(:))))):0),2)+'0');
```

or this one that uses [`bitand`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitand.html) instead of [`bitshift`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitshift.html):

```
int2bin = @(d,n)char(~~bsxfun(@bitand,d(:),2.^(max(n,nextpow2(max(d(:)))):-1:0))+'0');
```

All versions above assume that `d` is a nonnegative [integer class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/integers.html) variable, e.g., `uint64(13339262925365424727)`, and that `n` is a nonnegative numeric scalar. You can find full-featured `int2bin` and `bin2int` functions [on my GitHub](https://github.com/horchler/int2bin-bin2int).