# Convert 64 bit numbers from binary to decimal using uint64

Tags: matlab

I want to convert 64 bit numbers from binary to decimal. Since `dec2bin` only supports up to 52 bits, I thought I could roll my own function and use `uint64` to go beyond this limit:

```
function [dec] = my_bin2dec(bin)
v = uint64(length(bin)-1:-1:0);
base = uint64(2).^v;
dec = uint64(sum(uint64(base.*(uint64(bin-'0')))));
end
```

However, it does not work as expected:

```
my_bin2dec('111000000000000000000000000000000000001010110101011101000001110')

ans =

  8070450532270651392

my_bin2dec('111000000000000000000000000000000000001010110101011101000001111')

ans =

  8070450532270651392
```

Whereas this is the correct result:

```
(111000000000000000000000000000000000001010110101011101000001110)bin 
= (8070450532270651918)dec

(111000000000000000000000000000000000001010110101011101000001111)bin 
= (8070450532270651919)dec
```

What am I missing? It seems like there is some operation still performed using 52bit double arithmetic, but I don't know which one.

I checked if the operations are available for `uint64` and it seems that the ones I use (`power`, `times`, `sum`) are there:

```
>> methods uint64

Methods for class uint64:

abs         bitxor      diff        isinf       mod         plus        sum         
accumarray  bsxfun      display     isnan       mpower      power       times       
all         ceil        eq          issorted    mrdivide    prod        transpose   
and         colon       find        ldivide     mtimes      rdivide     tril        
any         conj        fix         le          ne          real        triu        
bitand      ctranspose  floor       linsolve    nnz         rem         uminus      
bitcmp      cummax      full        lt          nonzeros    reshape     uplus       
bitget      cummin      ge          max         not         round       xor         
bitor       cumprod     gt          min         nzmax       sign        
bitset      cumsum      imag        minus       or          sort        
bitshift    diag        isfinite    mldivide    permute     sortrowsc
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this in a function that scans the entries and assigns powers of 2 to each `1` and then sums the total?

Comment: @Adriaan the function does not necessarily have to look as I tried it, if you have a solution which works, please post it

Comment: Have you tried doing it in 32-bit chunks? I'm a bit busy right now, but I'll try to post a working sample in a bit.

Comment: [this question addresses the same issue for dec2bin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331789/matlab-dec2bin-gives-wrong-values)

Comment: @Daniel thanks for the link, however it does not explain why my `uint64` based implementation does not work as expected. Any idea?

Comment: It's `sum`. When I add the values from `base.*bin` in a loop, I get the correct result. Still investigating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were right in saying that

> It seems like there is some operation still performed using 52bit double arithmetic.

The problem is in line

> `dec = uint64(sum(uint64(base.*(uint64(bin-'0')))));`

The operation `sum(uint64(base.*(uint64(bin-'0'))))` gives a `double` result, which only has about 15 significant digits. That's why your lowest digits are wrong. Subsequent conversion into `uint64` doesn't help, because precision has already been lost.

The solution is to sum *natively* in `uint64`. This gives a `uint64` result with its full precision:

```
dec = sum(uint64(base.*(uint64(bin-'0'))), 'native');
```

Comment: great, I did not know about the `native` flag. I thought matlab would choose the correct implementation according the input

Comment: @m.s. It probably should. It's strange that `sum` chooses to produce a `double` result, when `uint64(1)*uint64(2)` for example gives `uint64` result

Answer (score 1):

Had the same thought as @beaker, break it into chunks:

```
%% dec2bin
x=intmax('uint64')
MSBs = dec2bin( bitshift(x,-32) ,32)
LSBs = dec2bin( bitand(x, hex2dec('FFFFFFFF')) ,32)
y = [MSBs LSBs]
%% bin2dec
MSBs = y(1:32)
LSBs = y(33:64)
z = bitor( bitshift( uint64(bin2dec(MSBs)) , 32 ) ,   uint64(bin2dec(LSBs)) )
% (now x = z)
```

Oddly enough, it seems that `dec2bin` doesn't give an error, but does give incorrect answers for 64 bit numbers:

```
dec2bin( intmax('uint64') )

ans =

10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```